# Change Buttons to visible after a User logs in

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, access-modifiers

I made an SQL database with a connection and a table with user and password. I managed to create a login following a guide. The code is working fine to login, but what I want to do is to show all other Buttons on the main Form after a user logs in.
I am using a Panel in the main Form to show the second Form. Clicking Buttons show a UserControl in the middle Panel.
I just want to update the `Button.Visible` value from `false` to `true` without opening a new main Form.

I can make the Buttons visible when the Form loads but not when I try to set a condition. I can't figure out how to set a condition that when a user logs in successfully, the other Buttons are set to visible and the login Button is hidden.

Part of code in the `MainLogin` UserControl.
The `MainMenu.UserAutherised` I added was to pass the `userID` from a TextBox to the `UserAutherised()` method in the `MainMenu` Form when the login is successful.

```
if (mread.Read() == true)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Login successfull");
  this.Hide();
  MainMenu.UserAutherised(text_userID.Text);
}
```

Part of code in `MainMenu`: I did this trying to solve the problem.
I thought that setting a bool to `true` when a user successfully logs in, I could have then called the `ShowButtons()` method to set Buttons to visible:

```
public static bool UserAutherised(string user)
{
    bool returnValue;
    string _user ="true";
    string _noUser ="false";
    bool _userID = bool.Parse(_user);
    bool _noUserID = bool.Parse(_noUser);
}

if (user == "")
{
    returnValue = _noUserID;
     return returnValue;
}
else
{
    returnValue = _userID;
    return returnValue;
}
```

I get the bool value as far as I can understand from debugging, but when I try to use the `if` statement in the `ShowButtons()` method, I can't figure out how to get the bool value from `UserAutherised()` to `if(UserAutherised())` to show the Buttons when the value is `true`.
I hope I described the problem well enough.

**EDIT 1:**

I tried the same `event Action` syntax to get the position and access for the user logging in. In the `MainLogin` form i added the following:

```
public event Action<string> ACCESS;
public event Action<string> POSITION;

string userAccess, userPosition;
```

and then i added the following in the `mread.Read` if-statement:

```
Sqlcommand cmd_get_position_Access = new SqlCommand (
"SELECT, Access FROM Users WHERE position = @position AND Access = @Access", dataconnection);

SqlParameter _position = new SqlParameter("@position", 
SqlDbType.NVarchar);
SqlParameter _access = new SqlParameter("@Access", SqlDbType.NChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add(_position);
cmd.Parameters.Add(_access);

userPosition = mread["position"].ToString();
userAccess = mread["Access"].ToString();
```

I get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to Invoke the new events so i added the following if-else statement to fix it:

```
if (ACCESS == null || POSITION == null)
{
  return;
}
else
{
ACCESS.Invoke(userAccess);
POSITION.Invoke(userPosition);
}
```

In the `MainMenu` button click event:

```
var userLogin = new MainLogin();
panel_Main.controls.Add(userLogin);
userLogin.userLogged += UserLogged;
userLogin.ACCESS += UserAccess;
userlogin.POSITION += Position;
userLogin.Show();
```

When debugging i can see that i get the Access value from database table. But when i try to use a method with  if-statements but the conditions are skipped even when true. I also tried the switch-statement but same thing happens to cases. They are skipped. For example if admin login i get `access yellow` but case is skipped. Same thing happens to the if-statements conditions. `Access is yellow` and condition is true but if-statement is skipped. **Why are they skipped when conditions are true?**

```
private void UserAccess(string access)
{
  switch (access)
  {
     case: "yellow":
           userAdmin();
           break;
     case: "green":
           userGreen();
           break;
     default:
           break;
   }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
I found the problem. It turns out to be in the User table. Access was set to `nchar` data type which add spaces to the value. `Access` was getting the `string` `"yellow     "`. I changed data type to `varchar` and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using static method to access MainMenu?

I think it would be better to declare event in MainLogin form like:

```
public event Action<string> userLogged;
```

and invoke it after this.hide:

```
userLogged.Invoke(text_userID.Text);
```

And in MainMenu form create a handler for this event:

```
void UserLogged(string user)
{
   if (user != "")ShowButtons();
}
```

And subscribe to userLigged event before showing MainLogin form like:

```
MainLogin loginForm = new MainLogin();
loginForm.userLigged += UserLogged;
loginForm.Show();
```

Comment: Wow! that was so simple. I haven't thought of declaring events. It works like a charm. Thank you!